# Can't serialize arraylist that contains JLabel

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to serialize an arraylist with a chart object, the only problem is that the object contains JLabels, IOException (failed to load image contents)

```
                ArrayList<Chart> al = new ArrayList<Chart>();
                al.add(new Chart("AAPL", 100, 1));
                ObjectOutputStream oot = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "test.txt"));
                oot.writeObject(al);
                oot.close();
```

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize GUI elements?

Comment: I am trying to serialize a chart, so when you restart the program, it would load up the chart, etc

Comment: Serialize the data that produces the chart.  Create and update the Swing components when you start the Swing application.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I was thinking of making a new class called "DataPackage" then adding the data, and later collecting it

Comment: Remember also that serialization is not recommended as long term storage. It's better to save data in a format that doesn't depend on the structure of your classes. Like JSON, XML, etc. Or in a proper database.